# Return value of Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Updater\RootPackageRetriever::getOriginalEdition() must be of the type string, null returned

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento2.4

We are upgrading magento2.4.3 to 2.4.4 using

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition:2.4.4
```

also tried with `--no-update`

unfortunately, we are facing an issue with the error

```
Return value of Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Updater\RootPackageRetriever::getOriginalEdition() must be of the type string, null returned
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Following the official guide:

(https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/prepare/prerequisites.html?lang=en)

I understood the right command to run:

`composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update`

then you can run the command with 2 params:

base-project-edition and base-project-version

for example:

`composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update --base-project-edition 'Open Source' --base-project-version 2.4.2`